# Interface Naming Convention (Interface Name clashes with Component Name)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an interface called `Widget` which is used throughout my project. However, it is also used as props for a component called `Widget`.

What is the best way to handle this? Should I change the name of my `Widget` interface? I've seen other people talk about NOT using `IWidget`, but no one talks about what to do instead. Thanks!

Comment: Don't rename them if they express the intentions clearly, but rename imports wherever necessary (again - to express your intentions more clearly). Eg: in a module with the component you could import the former as `WidgetProps`.

Comment: @zerkms Ahhh, ok thanks!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The convention is to use the `Props` suffix.

## Example

For `Widget` it would be `WidgetProps`.

Answer (score 2):

Although, as suggested, it is a good practice to have Props interfaces suffixed with `Prop`, if you have a name clash because a component and an interface has the same name, and you absolutely can't do anything about it, you can always rename on import. Again, *not the best practice.*

```
// interfaces/Widget.ts

//Ideally, this should be renamed as WidgetProps wherever possible
export interface Widget {
  myProp: number;
}

export default Widget;
```

```tsx
//Widget.tsx
import * as React from "react";
import { Widget as WidgetProps } from "./interfaces/Widget";
// or, if it is default export
// import WidgetProps  from './interfaces/Widget';

export const Widget = (props: WidgetProps) => (
  <div>{/** do something with props */}</div>
);
```